# EACCES permissions error on OSX using Node fs mkdir

Tags: node.js, macos, unix, io, filesystems

I am logged in and running node from inside my home directory (process.env.HOME).

I run this command in my program:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const outputPath = path.resolve(process.env.HOME + '/' + outputDir + '/' + timestamp);
 fs.mkdir(outputPath, cb);
```

and I get this error in the callback:

> EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/Users/amills001c/suman_results/1452824453902'

even though I am in my directory; it should work, right?

How can I avoid this error when using fs, specifically `fs.mkdir`?

Comment: Does `/Users/amills001c/suman_results/` exist?

Comment: Each `mkdir` can only create a single level. If you need to create multiple levels, you need multiple `mkdir` calls, or use one of `mkdirp` packages to do it for you.

Comment: it exists but I might run the infamous sudo chmod -R 777 .

Comment: I guess I had to run chmod, because that did in fact make it work. But why?